# How to increase IF Statement performance in c++

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

I have a question about how to perform my IF Statements in a way which leads to achieve the best performance in C++. My question may seem very basic however I need to ask.

Let's say I have a message going to be sent over a network. the message type may vary. There are many types of messages.

Now my question is that is it better to categorize these messages into one groups or divide them in to some categories and sub categories and whether it have affection on the performance or not?

To illustrate the point consider:

```
if (msg.Type == T1)
else if (msg.Type == T11)
else if (msg.Tye == T12)
...
else if (msg.Type == T120)
else if (msg.Type == T2)
else if (msg.Type == T21)
else if (msg.Tye == T22)
...
else if (msg.Type == T220)
...
```

OR

```
if (msg.Type == T1)
{
    if (msg.Type == T11)
    else if (msg.Tye == T12)
    ...
    else if (msg.Type == T120)
}
else if (msg.Type == T2)
{
    if (msg.Type == T21)
    else if (msg.Tye == T22)
    ...
    else if (msg.Type == T220)
}
{
    ...
}
```

Which one is better in case of performance?

Please let me know if you need me to be more specific.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: This is almost certainly an over optimization. You should be focused on other concerns and constructs. For example, if first `if` statement can be a `switch` statement, then that would be faster.

Comment: In general evaluating fewer if statements will perform better, but  it's extremely unlikley to make any tangible difference to any real world code, so write clear code first: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil".

Comment: @Zeta The thing is I'm not sure whether it might be a bottleneck or not? I'm just considering it.

Comment: @user3530012 If you don't know, then you haven't experienced any specific performance problem related to it, so it is **not** a bottleneck. Anyway, profile first.

Comment: Your computer will be capable of evaluating several mllion `if` conditions per second, so don't lose sleep over this.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Of course I don't. We all ask questions which we don't know the answers.

Comment: Forget about performance. What about the readability and extensibility? Massive if-else is not a good idea for those.

Comment: BTW, the 2 snippets does 2 different things (as if `msg.Type == T1`, it can't be also equal to `T12`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is ... whether it have affection on the performance or not?

The answer is no. The difference is **100%** unlikely to cause a slowdown compared to network latency and how you handle packet send/receive (buffering, logic etc.). My advice is to set up the thing and run performance measurements before you optimize anything.

Comment: Certainly correct if not designing a multithreaded server process receiving input from several devices AND the number of message types is reasonnable AND the statistical distribution of types is comparable. But What if you have 1000 types and 2/3 of messages are of the last type in your if-chain ?

Comment: So you mean I don't need to worry about the number of message types or it is a wrong way to handle them with if else statements?

Comment: @Christophe I get your point. Therein lies the usefulness of performance measurements. user3530012 What i mean is, your particular design question is superficial compared to other possible reasons for slow connections. *your If statements are fine, I would choose READABILITY as the top priority, personally I might use individual if-return statements or a switch.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add an interesting alternative and some numeric facts to the already good answers.

**0.Use switch statement instead of if-chain**

A golden rule could be : *never do yourself what your compiler can do (much better) for you !*

The `switch` statement can be easily optimized by any decent compiler using a jump table:  1 operation in constant time will determine which `case` code to use. No difference if it's 10 messages or 10 000.  Here more about [jump tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table).

Of course this requires that message types are constants.

**1.Some background if you need to use if-chains**

Comparing an `int`  with a constant requires 2 CPU instructions: a compare (CMP) and a conditional jump (JNE).  With a modern processor, it's around 1 nanosecond.  Network  latency is around 30µs (30 000 nanosecs) for a good GBit ethernet implementation. Less than 30 000 messages ?  Don't worry too much !

However, if you work on high performance servers, with several network interfaces and a multithreaded feeding architecture, think about performance twice: 1GB-ethernet interface means processing in average 1 byte every 8 nanosecs per interface. And [10GBEhternet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Gigabit_Ethernet) is comming.

**2.With only a few message types**

With a M message types and the same probability for each, the average selection overhead will be around *M/2* ifs (i.e. 100 types --> 50 nanosecs)

If some message types are more frequent than others, put them at the begin of the chain to experience dramatic improvement.  For ex, if 50% of messages correspond to the first type of your chain, the average overhead would be *3/4+M/4* ifs (i.e. 100 types -> 26 nanosecs)

**3.With many more types**

Then subgroups should be consiederd.  If you have G groups and M equiprobable messages types, it'll take an average of *G/2+M/G/2* ifs (i.e. 1000 types, 10 groups -->  55 nanosecs, compared to 500 nanosecs with a simple if-chain).

**4.Readbility and extensibility**

A switch or an ifchain of several hundreds of entries is extreamly dificult to read and hence error prone.

An easier to maintain alternative could be the use of the [command design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to build during the initialization a table of commands where the message type would be the index.  Almost as efficient as the jump table but easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing into sub categories will be better.
Also, you can use switch case. The compiler will optimize the comparisons for you.

Comment: Isn't the answer depending on the statistical distribution btw message types and the way you verify group appartenance ?